# aggregation in mongodb via mongoose in expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

I have designed a database that has a model named categories. in this model, each category has an id itself and a parent property that shows if the category is under another one's branch or not (for example nodejs is a child of web development category). I want to iterate through it in a way that I can show parents and the categories that have their id as parent.
this is an example of a parent document :

```
{
  "title": "web development",
  "_id": "64f04d6b81e4439030ed6073"
  "__v": 0
}
```

and this is an example of a child document:

```
{
  "title": "nodejs",
  "parent": "the id of web development"
  "__v": 0
}
```

and I want my output to look something like this when I want to fetch parents only:

```
    [
 {
     "_id" : "64f04d6b81e4439030ed6073",
     title:"web development",
     children : [the categories that have the mentioned id in parent property]
 },
    other parents....
    ]
```

I want to return each parent in an array of objects and each object has a children property which includes other categories that have nominated that parent.
I would really appreciate any help or hints you can give.

Comment: can there be children of children

Comment: no there are only parents and their children no more depth

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fK0TR2hgLKp something lik this?

Answer (score 0):

As far i'm understanding what you want is to get all the children for their respective parent!

if you want to achive, you can store the foriegn key in the children table as the reference of parent.

```
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

    {
        name: String,
        description: String,
        userId:
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user',
        },
        image: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'image cannot be null'],
        }
    },


)
```

this model is from blog app on which i'm currently working!

you see what i'm doing here is that storing the user id as a reference in my blog table.

now how can i get all blog to respective user??? or in your case the childrens for respective parent,here is the example query.

```
  const blogs = await blogModel.find({
  userId: user.id
   })
```

hope this helps you up